# Refresh fragment or listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have been trying to refresh my fragment or list view for the past 30 hours.

I have tried EVERYTHING:

- detaching and attaching the fragment;
- replacing the ViewPager which my fragment is located in with a new instance
- notifyDataSetChanged() for the list view adapter
- disabling addBackToStack for the FragmentTransaction

but NONE work! It still remains the same (as if nothing happened)!

Sigh... does anyone know how to do this properly? Thank you very much!

OK so here is my code:https://github.com/Tick-It/app

The associated code is located at com.tickit.InterfaceActivity and com.tickit.HomeFragment.

Comment: Posting your code would help.

Comment: Do you have any examples of the code you are running, so as we can pinpoint the issue? What you've asked help with is very broad

Comment: when do you want to refresh you fragment? i mean on some event or coming back from some activity or something else.

Comment: Please provide the code to your ListViewAdapter! It sounds like you might @override hasStableIds()...

Answer (score 0):

Whithout the code I supouse you have a listView inside a fragment and you want to update that list when something changes.

What I usually do is inside onResume() function of the fragment I set another time the list.

For example:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        setList(getActivity());
    }
```

and the setList() function is:

```
public static void setList(Context context)
{
    if( tableName != null )
    {
        cursor = helper.getCursor(tableName);   
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                    cursor, columns, to, 0);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

I don't know if that is the best way but it works.

Comment: Nope I tried that already and it does't work. Nothing happens! It's like the code was never ran!